# How to multiprocess async/await functions in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I need to run an event every 60 seconds to all my cars.  My problem with the code below is the while loop doesn't end until the timeout (60) does and hence only the first car in cars is run.

```
class RunCars(BaseEvent):

    def __init__(self):
        interval_seconds = 60  # Set the interval for this event
        super().__init__(interval_seconds)

    # run() method will be called once every {interval_seconds} minutes
    async def run(self, client, cars):
        for car in cars:        
            channel = get_channel(client, "general")
            await client.send_message(channel, 'Running this '+str(car))
            await msg.add_reaction(str(get_emoji(':smiley:'))) 
            
            reaction = None
            while True:
                if str(reaction) == str(get_emoji(':smiley:'))
                    await client.send_message(channel, 'Finished with this '+str(car))
                try:
                    reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60, check=check)
                except:
                    break
```

I tried changing the code into a multithreaded process but had trouble with async/await inside the function and problems with pickling the function itself.

I'd appreciate any suggestions for how to go about this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `asyncio` module lets you execute multiple `async` method concurrently using the `gather` method. I think you can achieve the behavior you want by defining a method that runs a single car, and then replacing your `for`-loop with a call to `gather`, which will execute multiple `run_one` coroutines (methods) concurrently:

```
import asyncio

class RunCars(BaseEvent):

    def __init__(self):
        interval_seconds = 60  # Set the interval for this event
        super().__init__(interval_seconds)


    async def run(self, client, cars):
        coroutines = [self.run_one(client, car) for car in cars]
        asyncio.gather(*coroutines)

    async def run_one(self, client, car):
        channel = get_channel(client, "general")
        await client.send_message(channel, 'Running this '+str(car))
        await msg.add_reaction(str(get_emoji(':smiley:'))) 
          
        reaction = None
        while True:
            if str(reaction) == str(get_emoji(':smiley:'))
                await client.send_message(channel, 'Finished with this '+str(car))
            try:
                reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60, check=check)
            except:
                break
```

In general, when writing async code, you should try to replace sequential calls to `async` methods - basically `for`-loops that call `async` methods - with `gather` statements so they execute concurrently.

Comment: I agree in principle,  but this answer doesn't explain why his code isn't working. Admittedly it's difficult to tell, as the question should be more focused. As it is it implies too many aspects

Comment: @mackorone thank you very much for your answer. this what i was trying to figure out. it really sucks that stackoverflow has become such a negative place. Some people assume it needs to work a particular way, the truth is never so obvious

Comment: @Pynchia yea, I wasn't about to try to explain asyncio just to answer the question. And echan00, happy to help!